# How to highlight currently speaking text of AVSpeechSynthesizer in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, uiwebview, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a word document loaded in webview. I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer to narrate the document. I want to highlight the currently narrating text. Using AVSpeechSynthesizer `delegate` method we could get the range of currently speaking string. Is there a way to highlight this range of string in the web view?